# Install game on flash drive and save to hard drive

Tags: xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 Arcade, with a 20GB hard drive, and it's pretty full.

I scratched my Assassins Creed game disc, but it still works and now I want to install it.

I can't erase stuff on the hard drive since they're not my games installed on it, but my brothers. Please help I'm too nervous to play Assassins Creed in fear I might scratch it again, rendering it useless.

So my question is, can I install it to a USB flash drive and still save to the hard drive?

If not, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install games to a USB stick. Most games are 5-7GB, so you'll need to make sure that your USB stick can accommodate that. Note that the maximum size supported by the Xbox 360 is 32GB. If yours is larger than that, you'll want to partition it first so that there is a 32GB partition.

The location of save games is completely independent of where the game data itself is stored. Remember, you don't have to install a game - if you're running it from the disk, save games can't be written there so in that case they must be saved elsewhere.

As @Strike said, if the game doesn't prompt you for what storage device to use when you start it up, you can change that in the options somewhere. Also note that if you only have one storage device, that prompt won't be shown since there isn't a choice for you to make.

Comment: I believe that with the latest xbox360 update (Fall 2012), the storage size of the USB stick capacity was increased to 32GB.  (http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive)

Comment: @DavidGrove Thanks, I updated my answer to indicate that.

Comment: @AndyMendoza If this answered your question, you should mark it as the answer to the question so it no longer shows up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Saving to hard-drive (or some other memory device) is not going to be a problem as all Xbox games have an option to select where you want to save to / load from. If you are not asked when you start the game, checking the options menu will reveal that option.

Also, I just went and tested if I could install it to a USB-stick and while it told me to select the memory unit, it didn't display the USB-stick as an option. 
I could further not copy an installed game from HDD to the USB-stick as the console told me that I'm `not allowed to move or copy the selected item`.

But then again I only used a USB-stick with 512 MB in size, so that could also have been the reason why it didn't work. I suggest you just pick a big enough memory device and just try out if its possible to install to a flash drive, the Xbox will either allow it or not and it's not like that will cause damage to any saves or installed games you already have on the hard disk.

If the Xbox doesn't allow it however, than I suggest you go talk to your brother to see what he could delete to make you able to install the game.

When all of this fails, a scratched disk should be covered by the guarantee of the store you bought it from. Ask them to provide you a new copy of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install a game on an external drive and have game saves on the internal drive.
I have successfully tested this idea with a 320 GB internal drive and a 250 GB external drive on my system.

Adding to @Adeese's response, the maximum supported size as of now (2019) is 2 TB.
(https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/using-usb-flash-drive)